# How to reset to default in Word 2003 the setting "Allow row to break across pages"?

Tags: microsoft-word-2003

MS Word MVPs suggesting [creation of a table style](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/word/thread/ae5ca218-ee6b-4157-a8a0-ef501c018921/), replacing the default one to have the rows broken across pages disallowed globally. Is there a step by step explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have Word 2003 installed, but by my recollection, this should accomplish what you are asking.

1. Open Word 2003, go to `Table`, `AutoFormat` then select `Table Grid`.
2. Click on `Modify`
3. In Format, choose `Table Properties`
4. In the Row tab, uncheck `Allow row to break across pages`
5. Click `OK`
6. Select the check box "Add to template" on top of Format button
7. Click `OK`
8. Click `Apply`

Choose `Yes` if you see message asking if `Do you want to save the
changes to Normal.dot` when you close Word .